# Why am I getting an IndexError when I input nothing and just press return?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a small number guessing game, and have defined a function to ask a yes/no question:

```
def again(question):
    quit_loop = False
    while quit_loop == False:
        try:
            again = str(input("\n" + question + " [y/n] ")).lower().strip()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            quit("\nAbort! Abort!\n")
        except:
            print("You have to enter something...")
            continue
        else:
            if again[0] == 'y':
                return True
            elif again[0] == 'n':
                return False
            else:
                print("Please enter either y or n...")
```

It runs fine, except for one thing. At the input prompt, if you don't type anything and just press return, you get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "guess.py", line 112, in <module>
    main_game(number, guess, prev_guesses)
  File "guess.py", line 109, in main_game
    guess_again(number, guess, prev_guesses)
  File "guess.py", line 58, in guess_again
    guess_again = again("Would you like to give it another go?")
  File "guess.py", line 77, in again
    if again[0] == 'y':
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I've put in the except: block to try and handle this error, but it doesn't work. I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I've spend ages on this and it has me stumped!

Is anyone able to point out where I've gone wrong and how to make it work as intended please?

Comment: Entering nothing is not an error so it is not caught. By the way: `input` already returns a `str` so no reason to cast it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter in nothing you have `again = ''` as there is no error with an input of nothing. In line 77 you then try and get the 0th index (first character) of the string 'again', but it has a length of 0 and so there is an index out of range error.

In order to see if they have entered in nothing, simply do the check

```
if again == "":
   Print("You need to enter something")
```

Or in this case, something like:

```
if again[0] != "y" or again[0] != "n":
   Print("Please enter y/n")
```

Comment: Thank you, that sorted it! I did also manage to fix it by adding `again += ' '` on the line below the input function, but your solution is much more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

## By my understanding your error occurs here:

```
if again[0] == 'y':
   return True
elif again[0] == 'n':
   return False
else:
   print("Please enter either y or n...")
```

In

```
again = str(input("\n" + question + " [y/n] ")).lower().strip()
```

If there is no input, when you run

```
if again[0] == 'y'
```

there is no again[0] because again is empty. Hence, Index error: string out of range.

To fix this make sure that again is not empty before you check if its first letter is y or n. If again **is** empty, it is not an error, so try will not catch it.

Answer (score 0):

When you press enter, you input an empty input, so it does not raise any exceptions and passes to else clause, where you try to access element `0` of empty `again` which throws error. You can check for again content before calling `again[0]`. Try:

```
def again(question):
  quit_loop = False
  while quit_loop == False:
    try:
        again = str(input("\n" + question + " [y/n] ")).lower().strip()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        quit("\nAbort! Abort!\n")
    except:
        print("You have to enter something...")
        continue
    else:
        if not again:
             print("You have to enter something...")
             continue
        elif again[0] == 'y':
            return True
        elif again[0] == 'n':
            return False
        else:
            print("Please enter either y or n...")
```

You also do not need `else` statement here. You can make it neater like:

```
def again(question):
  quit_loop = False
  while quit_loop == False:
    try:
        again = str(input("\n" + question + " [y/n] ")).lower().strip()
        if not again:
             print("You have to enter something...")
             continue
        elif again[0] == 'y':
            return True
        elif again[0] == 'n':
            return False
        else:
            print("Please enter either y or n...")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        quit("\nAbort! Abort!\n")
    except:
        print("You have to enter something...")
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like that:

```
if again and again[0] == 'y':
    return True
elif again and again[0] == 'n':
    return False
else:
    print("Please enter either y or n...")
```